# How to destroy session stored in MongoDB (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js

Currently I let my ReactJS client make a request to the `/logout` endpoint on my NodeJS server in order to destroy the session. It looks like this:

```
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    // for express-session
    req.session.destroy();
    res.clearCookie('connect.sid');

    res.status(200).send('User has been logged out');
});
```

I use `connect-mongodb-session` to store the session.

However, neither the session get's destroyed (it's still visible in MongoDB) and also the cookie `connect.sid` remains persistent at the client side.

---

I can of course also remove the session from the DB manually, however, I believe this is not the conventional way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
  router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
         if(req.session) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 0
        delete req.session
      }
        res.status(200).send('User has been logged out');
    });
```